# Find the 3 longest words from string

Tags: php

What I need to add to this script to get 3 longest words from string?

```
<?php
$text = 'one four eleven no upstairs';
$arr = explode(" ", $text);
$max = $arr[0];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    if (strlen($arr[$i]) > strlen($max)) {
        $max = $arr[$i];
    }
}

echo $max;
?>
```

Please help to modify the script. We have to not use the `usort` function.

Comment: why can't you use those functions, is this for school?

Comment: yes,  this is for school.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be like this:

- Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get the words of the string in an array
- "Partially" sort the array elements in descending order of length
- Use a simple `for` loop to print the longest three words from the array.

So your code should be like this:

```
$text = 'one four eleven no upstairs';
$arr = explode(" ", $text);
$count = count($arr);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $max = $arr[$i];
    $index = $i;
    for($j = $i + 1; $j < $count; ++$j){
        if(strlen($arr[$j]) > strlen($max)){
            $max = $arr[$j];
            $index = $j;
        }
    }
    $tmp = $arr[$index];
    $arr[$index] = $arr[$i];
    $arr[$i] = $tmp;
    if($i == 3) break;
}

// print the longest three words
for($i=0; $i < 3; $i++){
    echo $arr[$i] . '<br />';
}
```

**Alternative method:** (Using predefined functions)

```
$text = 'one four eleven no upstairs';
$arr = explode(" ", $text);
usort($arr,function($a, $b){
    return strlen($b)-strlen($a);
});
$longest_string_array = array_slice($arr, 0, 3);

// display $longest_string_array 
var_dump($longest_string_array);
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to write - we have not use functions like sort, array_slice...Just to change my code above.

Comment: @Sven I've completely updated my answer. Please test your application with the updated code snippet(s).

Comment: @Sven What do you mean *more easy*? The given solution(s) are fairly easy to understand. Moreover, what you're doing wrong in your code is, you're just finding **one longest word** from the array, not the three longest words in descending order.

Comment: Yes, i know. I thought that we should be dd just a couple strings to my code to make solution for 3 longest words.

Comment: @Sven I'm afraid that's not possible. You have to write proper code to get three longest words from the array, which is not possible just by adding *couple of strings*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own comparative function and pass it with array to usort php function.
Ex.:

```
<?php
function lengthBaseSort($first, $second) {
    return strlen($first) > strlen($second) ? -1 : 1;
}

$text = 'one four eleven no upstairs';
$arr = explode(" ", $text);
usort($arr, 'lengthBaseSort');

var_dump(array_slice($arr, 0, 3));
```

It will output 3 longest words from your statement.

*According to author changes*:

If you have no ability to use usort for some reasons (may be for school more useful a recursive function) use following code:

```
<?php
$text = 'one four eleven no upstairs';
$arr = explode(" ", $text);

function findLongest($inputArray) {
    $currentIndex = 0;
    $currentMax = $inputArray[$currentIndex];
    foreach ($inputArray as $key => $value) {
        if(strlen($value) > strlen($currentMax)){
            $currentMax = $value;
            $currentIndex = $key;
         }
     }
     return [$currentIndex, $currentMax];
}

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $result = findLongest($arr);
    unset($arr[$result[0]]);
    var_dump($result[1]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, i added some conditions above.

Comment: We have not use function usort.